# Azure Devops pipeline SSH error connection

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, serviceconnection

Is there a problem with Service connections?

After upgrade I can not create a private key in ssh service.

Formerly in the text field I had the option to upload, now the field is of type password and not file upload.

I tried to put the key in this field, but it does not work, I get the following pipeline error: 
**Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format.**

can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new service connection feature experience we provided recently, until now, it is keeping in **Preview** state. Anyway, need apologize for this unstable usage.

As work around, just go **Preview Feature** --> turn **New service connections experience** off, to use the old/stable service connection temporarily:

[image]

This [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/795587/view.html) has been taken by product group and is trying to fixing this unstable preview experience.

Comment: I have the same issue today but I can't turn off this feature.