# Connection to SSH from a pipeline in Azure DevOps is still not working

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I saw few other posts (in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078208/azure-devops-pipeline-ssh-error-connection)) about it but there are from last year. I still have this issue right now. I opened the **Preview features** from the **User settings** but I can't turn off this feature.

[image]

My pipelines use SSH connection to run some commands on a virtual machine (basically, pull a Docker image).

All my pipelines are failing. How can I fix it or update the SSH connections?

### Update

I set up the **Service connection**

[image]

and I use it in my pipelines with this YAML code:

```
- task: SSH@0
  displayName: 'SSH: stop shinyproxy'
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: $(server)
    commands: |
      echo $(pwd) | sudo -S docker stop shinyproxy
    failOnStdErr: false
  continueOnError: true
```

All pipelines, new and old, get the same error

> ##[error]Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error: All configured authentication methods failed
>
> at doNextAuth (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:803:21)
>
> at tryNextAuth (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:993:7)
>
> at USERAUTH_FAILURE (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:373:11)
>
> at 51 (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/handlers.misc.js:337:16)
>
> at Protocol.onPayload (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:2025:10)
>
> at AESGCMDecipherNative.decrypt (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/crypto.js:987:26)
>
> at Protocol.parsePacket [as _parse] (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:1994:25)
>
> at Protocol.parse (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:293:16)
>
> at Socket. (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/SSH_91443475-df55-4874-944b-39253b558790/0.213.0/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:713:21)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28) {
>
> level: 'client-authentication'

[image]

I have never had this issue before.

Comment: This feature was in preview 3 years ago, maybe it's public already. Can you update your question with the exact error?

Comment: Hi, could you directly use the ssh key into the VM without any issue? If so, do you use MS-hosted agent or self-hosted one? What about use self-hosted one for a try? Does it works if you move the SSH task and use an inline bash script task to run the same command? What about removing the existing SSH service connection and create a new one? Does it have the same issue?
Also I find two links related to your issue for your reference, you could kind try to see whether it works.

Comment: Here are the links:                         
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73560296/failed-to-connect-to-remote-machine-verify-the-ssh-service-connection-details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-ssh-connection

Comment: @AntoniaWu-MSFT Hi, I can connect to SSH from my laptop using the certificate. The VM is on Azure. I use MS-hosted agent. I haven't try the self-hosted one because I have a lot of pipelines that they were working until few days ago (they connect to different VM in Azure). I created multiple times the new SSH service connections with the same result. I haven't touch the old one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73560296/failed-to-connect-to-remote-machine-verify-the-ssh-service-connection-details), highlighted by [Antonia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19229290/antonia-wu-msft), the solution has to be applied on the Ubuntu machine.

To fix it, open **Terminal** and edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and, at the end of  it, add this line

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

After that, restart. It is working for me.

[image]